# python mysqldb how to correctly escape urls

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to correctly escape urls to enter into a mysql connection, but apparently I'm doing it wrong:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="...",passwd="...",db="...")
>>> cur = db.cursor()
>>> cmd = "insert into S3_data (url) VALUES ('http://google.com')"
>>> cur.execute(cmd)
1
>>> cur.execute(MySQLdb.escape_string(cmd))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#49>", line 1, in <module>
    cur.execute(MySQLdb.escape_string(cmd))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 220, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    r = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 371, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 335, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\\'http://google.com\\')' at line 1")
```

As you can see the command works ok, but the escaping fails. What am I missing here?

Also, does escape string handle multi-byte encodings?

Thanks

Comment: Try `\'http://google.com\'`

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use parameters you shouldn't have a problem.

```
cmd = "INSERT INTO S3_data (url) VALUES (%s)"
args = 'http://google.com'
cur.execute(cmd, args)
```

Comment: well, the problem is that sometimes urls will have a quotation mark inside them for example... not to mention ";drop table" or something..

Comment: Using parameterized queries stops SQL injections like quotes and ";drop table" from being executed as a SQL command.

Comment: @WeaselFox this is precisely the point of prepared statements